# New model value is not assigned OnPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

After uploading a file and extracting the FileName, I'm not able to assign the value to my model before updating the database. The file is uploaded correctly, the other data in the form is updated and no errors occurs.

The form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="Product.Name" />
    <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
    @for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        <input asp-for="Product.ProductIntervals[i].Name" />
        [...]
    }
</form>
```

OnPostAsync:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(CreateEditProduct model, IFormFile imageFile)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();

    if (imageFile != null)
    {
        var fileName = imageFile.FileName;
        var uploadPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        imageFile.CopyTo(new FileStream(uploadPath, FileMode.Create));
        model.Product.Image = fileName;
    }

    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
        model.Product,
        "Product",
        x => x.Name,
        //x => x.Image
    ))
    {

        _dbContext.Update(model.Product);

        foreach (var x in model.Product.ProductIntervals)
        {
            bool newInterval = x.Id == Guid.Empty;

            var interval = new ProductInterval
            {
                Id = newInterval ? Guid.NewGuid() : x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                IntervalMonths = x.IntervalMonths,
                IntervalDays = x.IntervalDays,
                Priority = x.Priority,
                ProductId = model.Product.Id,
                Status = x.Status
            };

            if (newInterval)
            {
                await _dbContext.AddAsync(interval);
            }
            else
            {
                _dbContext.Update(interval);
            }
        }

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./index");

    }

    return Page();

}
```

The model:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductInterval> ProductIntervals { get; set; }
}

public class CreateEditProduct {

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }

}
```

I've tried with/without x => x.Image in the TryUpdateModelAsync with no difference.

What is wrong?

Comment: i think you're going to want to include the IFormFile in your model

Comment: Can you post your model class

Comment: @ThamaraiT Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Normally I do it exactly this way and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the link between your model and the `DbContext` - unless you specified it somewhere in the part of code that you simplified away.

Would e.g. adding `_dbContext.Update()` call to your controller method solve the problem?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(CreateEditProduct model, IFormFile imageFile, string existingImage)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();

    if (imageFile != null)
    {
        var fileName = imageFile.FileName;
        [...]
        model.Product.Image = fileName;
    }

    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
        model.Product,
        "Product",
        x => x.Image,
        [...]
    )){
        _dbContext.Update(model); // or model.Product if you only need to save changes to Product
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Alternatively you can call `_dbContext.attach(model);` right after validation check to let Entity Framework track related changes to your model.

Comment: You could be right. I didn't have that, but the other times I've done this I didn't. I've updated my question with a little more data, because when I insert `_dbContext.Update(model.Product);` I get an error when updating the intervals saying that the entity is already tracked.

Comment: Would it make any difference if I did `var product = new Product { Name = model.Product.Name, Image = imageFile };` instead of the `TryUpdateModelAsync`?

Comment: What specific error are you getting now when updating the intervals?

Comment: `InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ProductInterval' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.`

Comment: I'll update my answer then, since there is a bit too much code for a comment

Comment: Okay, after some more thinking: what would happen if you completely remove the manual code for updating intervals? Try commenting out entire `foreach (var x in model.Product.ProductIntervals) {}` block and see if the intervals are saved. The reason why I think it might work is that the error you get suggests the intervals in your collection are _already_ tracked by EF and you don't need to do manual work to update them.